# Git commit convention

Tags: git, commit, google-style-guide

Should I remove the articles (a, the) when writing the git commit message?
I found that a lot of commits often 'miss' the articles 'a' and 'the'.
I checked the `Google Style Guide` but couldn't find the right answer.

Is it just the committers missing the articles or is there some rules for this?

E.g. Which of the below messages should I use?

1) "Resize **the** resolution of **the** image and fix **the** minor error"

2) "Resize resolution of image and fix minor error"

Comment: It dosn't matter. This is more a question of correct English than anything programming related. Try the SE site on the English language.

Comment: as long as its clear to someone else what a commit has its ok. the 2nd option would be ok to me edit: that too... more of an english question

Comment: Second version follows the common convention "Git commit header line should be at most 50 characters long". See for example: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/5-useful-tips-for-a-better-commit-message

Comment: See https://conventionalcommits.org/

Comment: Tangentially related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42110/can-you-recommend-a-good-commit-message-template-guidelines-to-enforce-in-the

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will actually answer by saying that I prefer the second more concise version.  The reason I prefer the concise version is that it makes it easier for me to read your entire comment when viewing it from the Git bash, a tool like SourceTree, or a Git plugin in an IDE like IntelliJ.  In most of these tools, the available space to view a series of commits tends to be small, and getting the point across in as few words as possible has value.

In particular, with the Git bash comments which span more than the available space have to keyed over to view entirely.  So shorter comments, with the key information appearing sooner rather than later, might be preferable to someone reviewing your history.

Comment: I have taken a down vote for answering, but I will leave this up in case you want an opinion from someone who has used Git heavily for many years.

Comment: I prefer commit messages written as if they're an instruction. "Do this" rather than "I did this"